# Cajas de CSS se solapan por :link

Tags: css

He empezado esta semana con CSS y no entiendo por qué, en los dos `<div>` que voy a usar como caja/enlace, si uso en los dos `:link` en CSS se solapan, si solo uso `:link` en el primero no pasa nada:

```css
div[id="botonpagar"] :link {
  background-color: #fcd015;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  padding-left: 150px;
  padding-right: 150px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  border-bottom: 2cm;
  height: 100px;
}
    
div[id="botoncancelar"] :link {
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: rgb(231, 20, 20);
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  padding-left: 150px;
  padding-right: 150px;
  border-top: 100px;
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="botonpagar">
  <a href="http://google.com" class="table">pagar y continuar</a>
</div>
<div id="botoncancelar">
  <a href="lala.com" class="table">cancelar</a>
</div>
```

[image: No me juzgueis por la imagen, sé que es la web de un timo XD]

> Sé que será una tontería simple, pero para alguien que está empezando como yo, se me hace bola.

Answer (score 0):

El problema lo tienes en que los estilos se los estás dando al enlace, las etiquetas `<a>` no tienen comportamiento de bloque, lo tienen **inline**. Los elementos **inline** no respetan del todo las fronteras de los elementos adyacentes, razón por la cual en tu caso se estaban metiendo unos en el espacio de los otros.

Tal y como estás definiendo tus estilos te interesa que los enlaces tengan `display: block`.

```css
div[id="botonpagar"] :link {
  background-color: #fcd015;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  padding-left: 150px;
  padding-right: 150px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  border-bottom: 2cm;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
}
    
div[id="botoncancelar"] :link {
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: rgb(231, 20, 20);
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  padding-left: 150px;
  padding-right: 150px;
  border-top: 100px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="botonpagar">
  <a href="http://google.com" class="table">pagar y continuar</a>
</div>
<div id="botoncancelar">
  <a href="lala.com" class="table">cancelar</a>
</div>
```